# How To Change HTML Label "for" Using JS

Tags: javascript, html, label

I have a label targeting a checkbox like the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="greatId" name="greatId">
<label id="checkLabel" for="greatId">Check Box</label>
```

How could I use JavaScript to change the `for`'s target? I've tried the following to seemingly no avail.

```
document.getElementById('checkLabel').for = 'newTarget';
```

Comment: document.getElementById('checkLabel').htmlFor = 'newTarget';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to change attribute for any element using JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById('checkLabel').setAttribute("for","newTarget");
```